# In rails, does "if @user.save" actually save the object, or is it just a check?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newbie question! In many controller methods, I see something like

```
@user.doSomething
if @user.save
  #flash or redirect something
else 
  #flash or redirect something
```

In this case, is it checking *whether the object has been saved*, or does this *save the object, then checks whether it worked*?

Comment: Yep, it does save.

Comment: Yes, it does save. But you should not be asking such questions, instead you should go through some good rails tutorials. :)

Comment: I wish I didn't have to ask of course. Thing is, most tutorials skip what actually happens here (it is just used), hence my question!

Comment: Even better. Instead of following a tutorial, [read the docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @user.save
```

This will save the object if it's valid and return

- `true` if the `@user` is saved successfully
- `false` if the `@user` is not saved

See the example below

```
@user = User.new

@user.save
#=> false

@user = User.new(email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'foobar123')

@user.save
#=> true
```

Comment: "false if the object @user is not valid" - No, it will return false if the user was not saved (just as the method name suggests). Validation errors can prevent save, yes, but so can other things.

Comment: Edited to avoid confusion

Comment: yeah, better now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.assign_attributes(params[:user])

  if @user.valid?
    @user.save!
    redirect
  else
    render
  end
end
```

This will save the user if it is valid, but if it cannot be saved due to some other reason an exception is raised.